# Laravel Eloquent: getDictionary with object value as value of result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Currently, `$mymodel->getDictionary();` returns:

[image: this]

What I am looking for is this:

```
"7gct5YaTvuxBmY2" => "Leadership",
"7NrXZepqczMSHqM" => "...",
"..." => "...",
...
```

The only way I have managed to do this is:

```
$construct_obj = OrganizationalConstruct::where('is_root', 0)->where('organization_id', $this->current_company->company_id)->get();
$constructs = [];
$constructs[''] = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($construct_obj); $i++) {
    $constructs[$construct_obj[$i]->organizational_construct_id] = $construct_obj[$i]->construct_name;
}
```

Is there an easier way of getting the format `"key" => "speific-column-value"` ?

I have tried:

- keyBy
- lists
- getDictionary
- map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `pluck` directly on the query, so that you don't pull down all attributes for all models:

```php
$dictionary = OrganizationalConstruct::where('is_root', 0)
                  ->where('organization_id', $this->current_company->company_id)
                  ->pluck('construct_name', 'organizational_construct_id');
```

**Note:** `lists` is deprecated, and will be removed in Laravel 5.3. Use the `pluck` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a simple answer actually. It looks like the `lists` methods can accept more than 1 argument, allowing me to pass through the `id` as parameter 1 and `name` as parameter 2 giving me the required result of `key => value` in one line.

So this:

```
$construct_obj = OrganizationalConstruct::where('is_root', 0)->where('organization_id', $this->current_company->company_id)->get();
$constructs = [];
$constructs[''] = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($construct_obj); $i++) {
    $constructs[$construct_obj[$i]->organizational_construct_id] = $construct_obj[$i]->construct_name;
}
```

becomes this:

```
$construct_obj = OrganizationalConstruct::where('is_root', 0)->where('organization_id', $this->current_company->company_id)->get();
$construct_obj->lists('construct_name', 'organizational_construct_id');
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Apparently `lists` method will be removed in Laravel 5.3, so use the `pluck` method instead. Have marked Joseph's answer as correct due to this.